# React - mapStateToProps - "state is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following problem: Using the code below I get the error:

> this.props.posts is undefined

As I am following the tutorial https://codeburst.io/redux-a-crud-example-abb834d763c9 an I typed everything correct I am totally confused already at the beginning of my React career. Could you please help me?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post';

class AllPost extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>All Posts</h1>
                {this.props.posts.map((post) => <Post key={post.id} post={post} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        posts: state,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllPost);
```

Comment: Could you please post your reducer and how you setup the store in `index.js`? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it sounds like your `postsReducer` isn't set up properly, or not connected to the store. Have you got [redux dev tools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) set up? It can help to debug these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your efforts!

The following is the postReducer:

```
const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return state.concat([action.data]);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default postReducer;
```

And here the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import postReducer from './reducers/postReducer';

const store = createStore(postReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You should declare an initial state inside your reducer file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an initial state. So your `this.props.posts` won't be `undefined`.

```
const initialState = {
  posts: []
}

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return { ...state, posts: [...state.posts, action.data]}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default postReducer;
```

The second error is located inside your `mapStateToProps` method. You need to access to `posts` redux state key. `posts: state.posts` like I did below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post';

class AllPost extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>All Posts</h1>
                {this.props.posts.map((post) => <Post key={post.id} post={post} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts, // you need to access to posts key
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllPost);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, state is being recognized. But I get another error:  this.props.posts.map is not a function :-(

Comment: Ok, could you `console.log(this.props.posts)` and tell me what type is this variable ?

Comment: I figured out where the mistake came from. I've edited my answer, could you tell me if it fix your issue ?

Comment: Thank you!! That's it! I love to work with professionals. :-)

Comment: Shit. The error just shifted: "TypeError: action.data is not iterable"

Comment: I've edited my answer. Don't spread your `action.data` anymore. `...action.data` => `action.data`